# What phrase would you use instead of "Likes" for an airline related forum?

Tags: microcopy, social-media

Implementing a socially driven forum for a major Airline (similar to stackexchange I guess) and trying to come up with a different name for the "Likes" functionality which is essentially like the Reputation points here in stack exchange.

Are there any naming best practices for this type of functionality?

Comment: Why are you avoiding 'Like'/'Dislike' in the first place?

Comment: Reason for this is we will be using the FB Link button to share on FB and we need this "Likes" functionality to make it obvious to the users that it's a in-site functionality. Does that make sense?

Comment: Just asked a friend if mine who's a commercial pilot. She suggested "affirm."

Answer (score 12):

The generic term is *up votes* or *upvotes* I guess. Up - like up in the *air* - and you could call the resulting number of upvotes the *altitude*. This comment's got *wings*!. [Too cheesy?]

Comment: You just soared straight into a mountainside, mate. But +1 for making me laugh.

Comment: To make it even cheesier and tongue in cheek, once users have attained a certain threshold of altitude points then you can badge them up and say they have joined the mile high club.

Comment: hahahaha. Love it guys.

Comment: Everyone loves a little cheese... so i'll add these on the list...
- Up this
- Up votes
- Wings (Give this Wings)

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for a term for reputation points, it's just begging to be either *miles* or *feet*. As for upvoting and downvoting, I agree with @Roger about the altitude approach - it could be measured in feet and get *boosts* for upvoting. Don't know about the downvoting though.

UPDATE To reduce altitude is usually to dive, but while you can boost someone, you can't really dive someone :). Maybe *drop*.

Comment: Thanks Vitaly. I was thinking along the lines of Miles but the problem is that the majority of Users will be members of the airlines Frequent Flyer program which also uses Miles as it's currency. As such I think this could cause confusion as to what they're doing.

Comment: You can use *virtual miles* or *v-miles* or something.

Answer (score 4):

Upgrade.  Like when you get upgraded to first class.

Comment: I like it (or should i say Upgrade it?). ;) That one will be added to the list. Thanks Smackfu.

Answer (score 2):

I'd also say the phrase should reflect the overall communications 'tone of voice /branding' of the company if its associated with a particular airline.

What would work for Virgin probably wouldn't work for British Airways.

Comment: Totally agree Phillip. And to be honest that will be what is the deciding factor in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You could base it around the way flights are gifted to regular customers and give questions / answers / posts / topics / whatever **airmiles**.

Disclaimer: It might seem a loose fit though as the unit of measurement is single digits. 10 airmiles might be a lot, but in terms of actual airmiles, maybe not so much...

Comment: Thanks Amadiere. Unfortunately as I mentioned above though, the difficulty in using Miles (or any variation) is that it's too similar to the Frequent Flyer miles they refer to everywhere on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Although a bit late now, it struck me of another idea, though it doesn't really fit your requirements exactly.

Still have a numerical representation of how many upvotes, but include an additional meta category for each one depicted as aircraft which get "better" on each (or after set numbers of) upvotes / downvotes. e.g.

```
0 - handglider
1 - Cessna
2 - private jet of some type
25 - A380
```

You'll have to pardon the lack of knowledge of planes on my part, but you could probably see where I'm going.
Displaying this could be done via a silhouette background on the vote count possibly, though there are a few alternatives depending on site design.

As I say, it's not an exact fit to what you asked (a word), but it can be used for a similar purpose.